# Profile says I have 13 rep (SO) but sum of my rep amounts to higher

Tags: support, reputation

My profile (and all the places where it shows) shows my rep at 13, however, taking a look at the upvotes and downvotes I get, it ammounts to higher. [Here](http://s13.postimage.org/vkso5fjp3/rep.png)'s a pic.

Comment: For the record, you're not in good stand.. most your questions have zero or negative votes and you have no answers - you're close to get question ban. Please think twice before asking, try to ask only good questions and try to answer some existing questions.

Comment: I didn't know... Thanks for the heads-up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *imagine* you lost rep points from a post which has since been deleted.

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and trigger a recalc via the button at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Matt's link http://stackoverflow.com/reputation  is not up-to-date anymore. It points to a non-existing page

Comment: Triggering a manual recalc is no longer needed: [Recent Reputation History Changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes). Still then, that link still (or again) exists for me, @Guido.